# Nifi Validate Records against set of value

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to validate nifi file fields against a set of values,

Ex : If the nifi field AGE in [7,8,9] and CLASS in [2,3,4]  consider this is valid record if not invalid record

Any idea how to achieve this in nifi

I tried ValidateRecord processor but couldn't find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ScriptedValidateProcessor`(https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ScriptedValidateRecord/additionalDetails.html)

**Example**:

Input JSON:

```json
[{
 "name": "test",
 "age": 8,
 "class": 3
},
{
 "name": "test2",
 "age": 6,
 "class": 7
}
]
```

**ScriptedValidateProcessor**:

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Script Language`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```java
if (record.getValue("class").toInteger() >= 2 && 
   record.getValue("class").toInteger() <= 4 && 
   record.getValue("age").toInteger() >= 7 && 
   record.getValue("age").toInteger() <= 9) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

**Output** (2 relationships - valid and invalid):

- `valid`:

```json
[ {
  "name" : "test",
  "age" : 8,
  "class" : 3
} ]
```

- `invalid`:

```json
[ {
  "name" : "test2",
  "age" : 6,
  "class" : 7
} ]
```

Comment: Thanks tony for your valuable replay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QueryRecord with something like `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE AGE IN (7,8,9) AND CLASS IN (2,3,4)`. Only the records matching the query will be in the output FlowFile.

Comment: Thanks Matt . I want the invalid records to log  and make a transformation rule

Comment: You can add another property for the inverse query, using `NOT IN` (or a `NOT` around the whole `AND` clause). Then you can route that relationship separately to wherever you like.